# Wordpress product as services

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

Is woocommerce/wordpress has a features that can integrate a services like house cleaning or baby sitting that can automatically calculate the prize depends on number of hour/s in serving? Thank you in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Woocommerce [Variable Product](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/) to create different timing periods for one service. 
For example you create a service as a product then assign different time periods as variables to that product so user can select desired option while purchasing the service.

Comment: Thank you so much!